# Java heap dump nid vs strace pid

Tags: java, strace

I trying to debug some slowness in my Java app running on Linux and I turned on strace and trying to see what is happening behind the scene and I have the following:

```
[pid  9667] 06:53:51.999552 futex(0x7f437ace3d4c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 29, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  9662] 06:53:52.001795 futex(0x7f437ace3d4c, FUTEX_CMP_REQUEUE_PRIVATE, 1, 2147483647, 0x7f437ace3d18, 30) = 1 <0.000025>
[pid  9667] 06:53:52.001831 <... futex resumed> ) = 0 <0.002275>
```

```
   So I can see my app main thread (9667) is blocked at some shared user space so I'm wondering what this 9662 is and trying to do a thread dump.
```

```
"main" #32 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f437af15000 nid=0x25c3 runnable [0x00007f42441fa000]
"ITRS.T" #28 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f437ab77000 nid=0x25bf waiting on condition [0x00007f4298155000]
"Log4j2-TF-3-AsyncLoggerConfig-3" #27 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f43794ce800 nid=0x25bd waiting on condition [0x00007f429885d000]
"Log4j2-TF-1-AsyncLogger[AsyncContext@764c12b6]-1" #25 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f4379302800 nid=0x25ba waiting on condition [0x00007f4299589000]
...
```

So 9667 corresponds to 0x25c3. However, I can't find that 9662 thread (ie with nid 0x25be). There's 0x25bf, 0x25ba, 0x25bd, etc)

Doesn't kill -3 dump all the threads? I'm just confused why there are threads not show up in thread dump and what other options are there.. I tried jstack and I can't find this 0x25be either. I will try jcmd next.

Thanks